# How to iterate through an unknown type?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I've got this function:

```
set<int> Search(const _Type & hayHeap) const {
        set<int>myset;
        for (vector<typename>::const_iterator i = needle.begin(); i != needle.end(); ++i) {
            cout << (*i) << " ";
        }
        return myset;
    };
```

and needle is defined like this:`vector<string> needle;`

Now I need to create another iterator, that will iterate through `hayHeap`. But the problem is, that I don't know, what type will it be. It could be a single `string` or `vector` of `<int>`/`<string>` as well. So when there is a `string`, it iterates only once, if there is some vector it iterates `(myVector.count()-1)`-times. How to make this type independent iterator?

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Type`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: `_Type` is a known type unless you use it as a template placeholder. Is `Search` a template function?

Comment: This sounds like a completely absurd requirement. Just overload the function three times, once for each variant. What would it even mean to have a vector<int> here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++03:

```
template <typename C>
set<int> Search(const C& hayHeap) const {
    set<int>myset;
    for (typename C::const_iterator i = needle.begin(); i != needle.end(); ++i) {
        cout << (*i) << " ";
    }
    return myset;
};
```

In C++11:

```
template <typename C>
set<int> Search(const C& hayHeap) const {
    set<int>myset;
    for (auto& i : needle) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    return myset;
};
```

Depending on your actual needs, you'd replace `int` by `typename C::value_type`

Comment: oh..I forgot to mention, that I can't change the declaration of Search function..it must stay, as it is.. ` set<int> Search(const _Type & hayHeap) const `

Comment: Then, don't change it. I changed only the _name_ of the `_Type` (which I did because names with leading underscores are frequently reserved for standard library implementation.

Comment: @MarkB Actually, my shortcut wording was quite careful. Read Pete's comment at the question for the _actual_ details. So, indeed, "names with leading underscores are _frequently_ reserved". Not always. (I didn't say it depends on compiler or library; it only depends on the rest of the identifier :))

Answer (score 1):

OK  I think I understood your question now. I think you are looking for some kind of type function. Something of this sort.

```
template<typename T>
struct my_selector {
    static void search(T& t) {
        cout << " Single string / int search" << endl;
        bool b = t == "needle";
        cout << b;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct my_selector<vector<T>> {
    static void search(vector<T>& needle) {
        cout << " Vector search" << endl;
        for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator i = needle.begin(); 
                      i != needle.end(); ++i) 
        {
           cout << (*i) << " ";
        }
    }
};

int main() {


  typedef std::vector<std::string> _Type;  
  _Type needle(4,"s");
  // Search function is selected based on type of _Type.
  my_selector<_Type>::search(needle);


  // typedef string _Type;  
  // _Type needle = "needle";
  // // Search function is selected based on type of _Type.
  // my_selector<_Type>::search(needle);


}
```